# BeautifulSoup filling missing information with "N/A" not working

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am practicing my web scraping skills on the following website: "http://web.californiacraftbeer.com/Brewery-Member"

The code that I have so far is below. It seems like I am getting the correct company count but I am getting duplicate rows in my CSV file, which I think occurs whenever a company is missing information. In multiple parts of my code I have tried to detect and replace missing information with the text "N/A", but it isn't working. I'm guessing that this issue might be related to the Zip() function but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
"""
Grabs brewery name, contact person, phone number, website address, and email address 
for each brewery listed on the website.
"""

import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://web.californiacraftbeer.com/Brewery-Member"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
each_company = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ListingResults_All_CONTAINER ListingResults_Level3_CONTAINER"})
error_msg = "N/A" 

def scraper():
    """Grabs information and writes to CSV"""
    print("Running...")
    results = []
    count = 0

    for info in each_company:
        try:
            company_name = info.find_all("span", itemprop="name")
        except Exception as e:
            company_name = "N/A"
        try:
            contact_name = info.find_all("div", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_MAINCONTACT"})
        except Exception as e:
            contact_name = "N/A"
        try:
            phone_number = info.find_all("div", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_PHONE1"})
        except Exception as e:
            phone_number = "N/A"
        try:
            website = info.find_all("span", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_VISITSITE"})
        except Exception as e:
            website = "N/A"

        for company, contact, phone, site in zip(company_name, contact_name, phone_number, website):
            count += 1
            print("Grabbing {0} ({1})...".format(company.text, count))
            newrow = []
            try:
                newrow.append(company.text)
            except Exception as e:
                newrow.append(error_msg)
            try:
                newrow.append(contact.text)
            except Exception as e:
                newrow.append(error_msg)
            try:
                newrow.append(phone.text)
            except Exception as e:
                newrow.append(error_msg)
            try:
                newrow.append(site.find('a')['href'])
            except Exception as e:
                newrow.append(error_msg)
            try:
                newrow.append("info@" + company.text.replace(" ", "").lower() + ".com")
            except Exception as e:
                newrow.append(error_msg)
        results.append(newrow)

    print("Done")
    outFile = open("brewery.csv", "w")
    out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='\n')
    out.writerows(results)
    outFile.close()

def main():
    """Runs web scraper"""
    scraper()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bs4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

> "If find_all() can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If
>   find() can’t find anything, it returns None"

So, for example, when `company_name = info.find_all("span", itemprop="name")` runs and doesn't match anything, it does not throw an exception and `"NA"` never gets set.

In this case you need to check whether `company_name` is an empty list:

```
if not company_name:
    company_name = "N/A"
```